# How To Resize Existing Texture In OpenGL 4.3

Tags: opengl, c++, textures

I would like to know how to resize an existing **OpenGL 4.3** texture while keeping the current contents.  i'm using `glTexImage2D()`.  Do I simply re-call `glTexImage2D()` with `nullptr` for the `data` paramater?

Comment: Quick question: Why do you want to resize it, but keep the data? What would it fill the rest of the space up? You can always just draw a texture twice as large as it is, it will interpolate automatically

Comment: Or if you shrink it you cannot keep the data: Something must be lost. Maybe you should talk a little about **what you're trying to do** rather than **how you're trying to do it**, because this is seeming like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I guess I used the wrong terminology.  I guess I'm looking to re-sample the image with that call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot.

You can create a new texture and [copy the contents of the pixel data from the old texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy) into the appropriate place of the new one. But `glTexImage` will reallocate the storage for the texture. And not like `realloc` does; it works like `malloc` followed by `free`ing the old memory.

Its best to avoid this problem by making the texture as large as you will reasonably need it to be, then living within that storage.